# Mensaje de NaN en texto parseado

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo que no entiendo porque al comparar los valores me arroja NaN ya que esta parseado.

Mi duda es porque precisamente al estar parseado creo que ya es un número-número como tal, es decir, ya no es un texto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    let dato1, dato2, dato3, num1, num2, num3, resultado;
    dato1 = window.prompt("Primer numero", "0");
    num1 = parseInt(dato1);

    dato2 = window.prompt("Segundo numero", "0");
    num2 = parseInt(dato2);

    dato2 = window.prompt("Tercer numero", "0");
    num3 = parseInt(dato3);

    if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3))
    {
        resultado = num1;
    }
    else if ((num2 > num1) && (num2 > num3))
    {
        resultado = num2;
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = num3;
    }

    document.write(`<h3>El mayor es ${resultado}.</h3>`);

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes un typo.  Estas igualando el tercer numero a la variable `dato2`.  Deberia ser `dato3`.

Comment: No estas declarando dato3, cambia eso y ya funciona dato3 = window.prompt("Tercer numero", "0");

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente tenía un error en la declaración, había puesto dato2 2 veces.

**Código corregido:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    let dato1, dato2, dato3, num1, num2, num3, resultado;
    dato1 = window.prompt("Primer numero", "0");
    num1 = parseInt(dato1);

    dato2 = window.prompt("Segundo numero", "0");
    num2 = parseInt(dato2);

    dato3 = window.prompt("Tercer numero", "0");
    num3 = parseInt(dato3);

    if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3))
    {
        resultado = num1;
    }
    else if ((num2 > num1) && (num2 > num3))
    {
        resultado = num2;
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = num3;
    }

    document.write(`<h3>El mayor es ${resultado}.</h3>`);

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: y cual era el error?

Comment: cuando asignaba los valores coloque 2 veces dato2!! en lugar de dato2 y dato3

Comment: Te recomiendo que valides que solo se puedan ingresar numeros, ya que hice la prueba y deja poner tambien letras, saludos.